# How to set null in update with ef core 7 ExecuteUpdateAsync SetProperty

Tags: c#, ef-core-7.0

I have this method:

```
public async Task<int> RemoveClassify(RemoveClassifyVm vm)
{
    return await _db.UserAccesses
        .Where(UserAccess => vm.userAccessIds.Any(userAccessId => userAccessId == UserAccess.Id))
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(UserAccess => UserAccess
         .SetProperty(UserAccess => UserAccess.ClassId, null)
        );
}
```

but get error : Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'SetPropertyCalls.SetProperty(Func<TSource, TProperty>, Func<TSource, TProperty>)' and 'SetPropertyCalls.SetProperty(Func<TSource, TProperty>, TProperty)'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

we must use : **(int?)null**

```
SetProperty(userAccess => userAccess.ClassId, (int?)null)
```

Comment: please mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
SetProperty(UserAccess => UserAccess.ClassId, UserAccess => null)
```

Comment: Please see @m-komaei's answer. Your answer will result in an ambiguous invocation error.